# Why MPI_barrier is not synchronized correctly?

Tags: fortran, mpi

The output of below fortran code

```
Program test
    Use mpi
    Implicit None
    Integer :: rank,num_process,ierr
    Real (8) :: a

    Call MPI_Init (ierr)
    Call MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_comm_world, rank, ierr)
    Call MPI_Comm_size (MPI_comm_world, num_process, ierr)

    Call random_number (a)
    Print *, 'rank = ', rank, 'a = ', a

    Call mpi_barrier (MPI_comm_world, ierr)
    Call random_seed ()
    Call random_number (a)
    Print *, 'rank = ', rank, 'a = ', a
    Call MPI_Finalize (ierr)
End
```

is something like

```
 rank =            1 a =   3.920868194323862E-007
 rank =            2 a =   3.920868194323862E-007
 rank =            3 a =   3.920868194323862E-007
 rank =            3 a =   0.937863842453073
 rank =            0 a =   3.920868194323862E-007
 rank =            2 a =   3.357612614239127E-002
 rank =            0 a =   0.928975653817377
 rank =            1 a =   0.481275889979884
```

**Why the print result is not synchronized at the `MPI_barrier`?**

The correct synchronized result should be something like this

```
 rank =            1 a =   3.920868194323862E-007
 rank =            2 a =   3.920868194323862E-007
 rank =            3 a =   3.920868194323862E-007
 rank =            0 a =   3.920868194323862E-007
 rank =            3 a =   0.937863842453073 
 rank =            2 a =   3.357612614239127E-002
 rank =            0 a =   0.928975653817377
 rank =            1 a =   0.481275889979884
```

Comment: It may be better to put the output as plain text in the question, rather than an image.  Also, please explain exactly what you expect/hope to see.  And, perhaps, as this is a question about buffering of standard output how you run the program.

Comment: @francescalus I updated my post : )

Comment: IO goes to a buffer, and maybe this is causing some wrong ordering. You could try to add a `flush()` after the first print.

Comment: @haraldkl Hi, haraldkl. How to add it? I got an error

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/1533717/577108, should be something like print *, 'something'; flush(6). Or, better use OUTPUT_UNIT from the iso_fortran_env module: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fFORTRAN_005fENV.html

Comment: @haraldkl I don't understand, I tried `call flush()`, didn't work. What is the unit for screen?

Comment: `use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : output_unit; ...; flush(output_unit)`.  Note, not `call flush`.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you. Ok, now the flush(output_unit) works. However, the output is still not synchronized.

Comment: If you want deterministic output, you should output from a single rank only.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thank you Hristo lliev.